# What are the default URLs for Django's User Authentication system?

Tags: python, django

Django's User Authentication system ( http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/ ) is incredibly helpful in working with users. However, the documentation talks about password reset forms and makes it seem like it takes care of it the same way it does user login/logout.

The default URL for login and logout is

/accounts/login/   &   /accounts/logout

Are there already defaults for changing the password, or do I have to build that functionality?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you look at [`django.contrib.auth.urls`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/urls.py) you can see the default views that are defined. That would be `login`, `logout`, `password_change` and `password_reset`.

> These URLs are normally mapped to /admin/urls.py. This URLs file is
>   provided as a convenience to those who want to deploy these URLs
>   elsewhere.
>   This file is also used to provide a reliable view deployment for test
>   purposes.

So you can just hook them up in your urlconf:

```
url('^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

As you probably want to customize those views (different form or template), in my opinion you will redefine these urls anyway. But it's a good starting point nevertheless.

Comment: This doesn't work for 1.6, i get `'module' object has no attribute 'urls'` error

Comment: @boussouira Works fine here, what exactly are you attempting to do?

Comment: the include should be wrapped in url() like so:
`url('^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),`

Comment: @CollinAnderson Why should url be used?

Comment: @CollinAnderson Okay, it seems the django documentation is nowadays only using the url function, I changed the post accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: patterns() is deprecated and url() needs to be used instead. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.8/#django-conf-urls-patterns

Comment: Django 1.9.8 py 2.7 `NameError: name 'include' is not defined` when without `from django.conf.urls import url, include`

Answer (score 4):

Just a heads up this should now be

```
from django.urls import include
path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
```