# NoReverseMatch error in password reset functionality django

Tags: python, django, forms, passwords, reset

I am trying to implement password reset funcitonality in django and below are my codes

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^signup/$', 'accounts.views.signup', name="signup_email"),
    url(r'^user/password/reset/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', {'template_name':'accounts/forgot_password.html',\
                               'post_reset_redirect' : '/user/password/reset/done/'}, name="reset_password"),
    url(r'^user/password/reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done'),
```

**forgot_password.html**

```
     <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="{% url 'reset_password' %}" class="reset_pass" id="reset_pass" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="user_email" style="font-size: 18px; color: #474747">Email</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input class="" id="id_email" name="email" type="text" value="">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <button type="submit" value="reset_password" class="btn btn-primary">Send me reset password</button>
                </div>
            </div>
       </form>
```

so when we go to the url `user/password/reset/` a `forgot_password.html` is displaying, and when i entered the email and submitted the form i am getting the below errors

[image]

and

**Error during template rendering**

```
In template /home/user/proj/virtualenvironment/apps/pro_utils/accounts/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html, error at line 7
```

[image]

Can any one please let me know why it is complaining `NoReversemtach` even though i am using builtin views ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add that url+view in `urls.py` as below

```
url(r'^user/password/reset/confirm/$', 
             'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'),
```

It presents a form for entering a new password.

You may also have to add this as well

```
url(r'^user/password/reset/complete/$', 
             'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete'),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the default urls defined in `django.contrib.auth.urls` by including

```
(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

to your `urls.py`.

The `password_reset_confirm` pattern require 2 additional parameters for the `uidb64` and the `token`:

```
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    'password_reset_confirm',
```

See also the answer here: [What are the default URLs for Django's User Authentication system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951203/what-are-the-default-urls-for-djangos-user-authentication-system)